# Why nagios is not rendering html in home page

Tags: nagios

I am using nagios and my config file i have `report = html`

The output is like this

```
Current Status: 
  CRITICAL  
 (for 0d 0h 1m 54s)
Status Information: CRITICAL - (1 errors in secure.protocol-2013-07-19-13-06-07) - Jul 19 13:05:08 server sshd[24321]: input_userauth_request: invalid user pandu
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;"><tr valign="top"><td class="serviceCRITICAL">tag rootlogin</td></tr><tr valign="top"><td nowrap width="100%" class="serviceCRITICAL" style="border: 1px solid black;">Jul 19 13:05:08 server sshd[24321]: input_userauth_request: invalid user pandu</td></tr></table>
\n
```

I am using this plugin

http://labs.consol.de/lang/en/nagios/check_logfiles/

with this option

```
–report=[short|long|html]This option turns on multiline output (Default: off). The setting html generates a table which display the last hits in the service details view.
```

Isnt it suppose to render it

Comment: What version of nagios is this? And what file is "report = html" in?

Comment: @Keith i am using latest nagios , and that is in config file `$options = 'report=html'`. `report=long` works fine  but thats just text . i want some color html

Comment: Not helpful. Which are you considering "latest nagios"?

Comment: @Keith sorry i have now edited the question with more details of plugin . I am using nagios core v3.5

Answer (score 1):

Find cgi.cfg, and look for "escape_html_tags":

```
# ESCAPE HTML TAGS
# This option determines whether HTML tags in host and service
# status output is escaped in the web interface.  If enabled,
# your plugin output will not be able to contain clickable links.

escape_html_tags=1
```